# Automatically resize stage if content is changed

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have AnchorPane created with SceneBuilder and corresponding Scene and Stage. AnchorPane contains VBox. All sizes of AnchorPane are USE_COMPUTED_SIZE. Heght of VBox is changed programmicaly, but sizes of Scene and Stage do not change.

How can I make them being autoadjusted to content size?

Answer (score 11):

The start() method of your Application class is passed a Stage object (called stage by the Wizard). If you declare a member variable of type Stage in that class (mStage), then the first thing you do in start() is save it:

mStage = stage ;

You can now do this anytime you need to (in your Application class of course):

mStage.sizeToScene() ;

If you need to do it from your controller class, you can give your controller a reference to your Application (or probably better, have your Application class implement an interface for the controller). Ah, you say, but my Application class doesn't have a reference to the controller, and visa-versa). Well, I've never liked the code that is generated by the wizard, because inflates the controller from the XML file without giving you a reference to it, which makes using the document-view-controller pattern hard. If you want to see how you can get a reference to the controller, see slide 8 (not page 8) of the following. If you further want to instantiate and then specify your own controller (I have a use case for which that is highly desirable) see slides 10 and 11:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxwc2NoaW1wZjk5fGd4OjVlODJiOTg2OTVlYzky

Comment: Hi, I am three years late, but can you clarify what it means to save your Stage to a member variable?  If I am loading a new .fxml and I want to window to resize to fit this larger scene, should I use `sizeToScene()` in my controller class?  Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question, in which I anticipate your next problem, so answered that as well. Apologies if that expansion answers something you already know. :-)

Comment: Thank you.  So, it looks like this references the controller in my main class, but is that a two way connection?  Like can I put something like `primaryStage.sizeToScene` in my controller class?  Thanks again.

Comment: If I'm understanding your problem, your controller needs a ref to your App class in order to tell it to resize its stage, and your App class can give it that so it can make the callback you show. I generally embed my Controller in a separate class that the App class instantiates, and 'this' can be passed to the constructor. Also, rather than access a public var in the App class,  I would have it implement an interface defined by the controller, so the controller can call something like mResizable.resize() ;

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for this the whole day!